# Handle ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] in python

Tags: python

I got this error with python's tcp socket

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "servidor_tcp_python.py",
> line 205, in 
> ejecucion_servidor()   File "servidor_tcp_python.py", line 27, in ejecucion_servidor
> data = connection.recv(10000) ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

```
#Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('x.x.x.x', 10000)
print('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(25)
while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print ('waiting for a connection')
    try:
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        print('connection from', client_address)
        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            #with decode we convert byte to string, default decode is utf-8
            data = connection.recv(10000)
            print("Datos recibidos sin decodificar: "+str(data))

            try:
                data=data.decode("utf-8")
                print("Datos recibidos decodificados: "+data)
                #
                #......                    #
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                break
            except ConnectionResetError:
                break
```

As you can see, I handle and catch the exception with the line

```
except ConnectionResetError:
                    break
```

But it is not working. Why? Should I close the connection after the except?

Comment: you are not try/catching `data = connection.recv(10000)` which is where the error comes from

Comment: thanks for the reply. I consult you, in the exception what should I do? close the connection? or nothing?

Comment: i can't answer that. that depends on what your business and technical requirements